# Using Infinity with AutomaticUnits

Tags: units

I am using the [AutomaticUnits](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7655/) package in Mathematica 10, and I am writing some unit checking functions. However, I run into a problem when I have an Infinity, since `Infinity*Meter = Infinity`, unlike `0*Meter = 0 Meter`. However, it seems to work when I do `Unit[Infinity, "Meter"]`. Is there a way I can get Mathematica to set `Infinity*Meter = Unit[Infinity,"Meter"]`?

I tried

`Unprotect[Times]; 
Times[Infinity,x_Unit]=Unit[Infinity,Last[x]]`

but the Times on the left hand side was evaluated first as shown by the DownValue

(`{HoldPattern[\[Infinity] x_Unit] :> Unit[Infinity, Last[x]]}`)

Comment: You may try `Meter /: Infinity Meter := Unit[Infinity, "Meter"]`. It seems to work but I have not tested it with the packages concerned. Do not try to modify core arithmetic functions like `Times`; they have special evaluation semantics and your own rules are likely to be ignored in certain contexts, or even to unexpectedly disappear altogether.